# ¿ Por qué se habilita el submit del formulario si el email es incorrecto en Angular?

Tags: angular

Si el formato de `email` no es válido, muestro el error y el boton del `submit` del formulario queda inhabilitado. El problema esta que cuando empiezo a borrar el `email` mal escrito en el `input`, el botón `submit` se habilita, de esta forma se podría enviar un email incorrecto al hacer submit. Cómo puedo evitar esto?

Aca el `componente.ts`

```js
form: FormGroup;
password2 = '';
user = {} as User;

 constructor(
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder, 
    public myValidationsService: MyValidationsService,
    public authService: AuthService,
    private router: Router
  ) { 
    this.buildForm();
  }

 buildForm() {
    this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
      email: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(80), Validators.email]],
      username: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(50)]],
      password: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(80)]],
      password2: ['', [Validators.required], {validator: this.checkPasswords }]
    });
  }
  
  
  deleteWhiteSpace(cadena: string) {
    // return cadena.replace(/\s{2,}/g, ' ').trim();
    const a = this.myValidationsService.deleteWhiteSpice(cadena);
    return a;
  }

  signUp(event: Event){
    event.preventDefault();
    if(this.form.valid){     

      //this.user = this.form.value; 
      this.user.registrationDate = this.currentDate;
      console.log(this.user);
   
    }
  }
  
  checkPasswords(group: FormGroup) {
  let pass = group.get('password').value;
  let confirmPass = group.get('password2').value;
  
  return pass === confirmPass ? null : { notSame: true }     
}
```

Aca el `component.html` con el formulario.

```html
<form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="signUp($event)">

    <div class="form-group mb-3">
        <label>Email</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" formControlName="email" [(ngModel)]="user.email" placeholder="Email">
        <div *ngIf="form.get('email').errors && form.get('email').dirty">
            <p class="text-danger" *ngIf="form.hasError('email', 'email') && form.get('email').touched">
                Ingrese un formato de email correcto.
            </p>
            <p class="text-danger" *ngIf="form.get('email').hasError('required')">
                Este campo es obligatorio!
            </p>
            <p class="text-danger" *ngIf="form.get('email').hasError('maxlength')">
                El email es muy largo!
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group mb-3">
        <label>Nombre de usuario</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="username" [(ngModel)]="user.username"
            placeholder="Nombre de usuario" (blur)="user.username = deleteWhiteSpace(user.username)">
        <div *ngIf="form.get('username').errors && form.get('username').dirty">
            <p class="text-danger" *ngIf="form.get('username').hasError('required')">
                Este campo es obligatorio!
            </p>
            <p class="text-danger" *ngIf="form.get('username').hasError('maxlength')">
                El nombre de usuario es muy largo!
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group mb-3">
        <label>Contraseña</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" formControlName="password" [(ngModel)]="user.pass"
            placeholder="Contraseña" (blur)="user.pass = deleteWhiteSpace(user.pass)">
        <div *ngIf="form.get('password').errors && form.get('password').dirty">
            <p class="text-danger" *ngIf="form.get('password').hasError('required')">
                Este campo es obligatorio!
            </p>
            <p class="text-danger mt-1" *ngIf="form.get('password').hasError('maxlength')">
                la contraseña es muy larga!
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group mb-3">
        <label>Confirmar contraseña</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" formControlName="password2" [(ngModel)]="password2"
            placeholder="Confirmar contraseña" (blur)="password2 = deleteWhiteSpace(password2)">
        <div *ngIf="form.get('password2').errors && form.get('password2').dirty">
            <p class="text-danger" *ngIf="form.get('password2').hasError('required')">
                Este campo es obligatorio!
            </p>
            <p class="text-danger" *ngIf="form.get('password2').hasError('maxlength')">
                la contraseña es muy larga!
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="text-center">
        <button [disabled]="form.invalid" type="submit" mat-raised-button color="warn"
            class="btn-block">Registrarse</button>
    </div>

</form>
```

```
my-validations.service.ts
```

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MyValidationsService {

  constructor() { }

  deleteWhiteSpice(str: string){
    const word = str.split(/\s/).join('');
    return word;
  }

}
```

Comment: Puedes crear un [mcve] en stackblitz.com? Con el código que tienes aquí no se puede recrear tu problema y claramente falta código (no estás usando `MyValidationsService` y no tenemos la función `checkPasswords`). Por otro lado, no me parece una buena idea usar a la vez un formulario reactivo y `ngModel` con el objeto `user`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45815176/is-using-ngmodel-in-reactive-forms-bad-practice

Comment: Tambien agregue al codigo  checkPasswords y MyValidationsService

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-trnlki?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Answer (score 1):

No es un problema de tu validador.

El siguiente es un correo valido según el estandar.

```
admin@mailserver1 Dominio local sin TDL
```

Esta es una lista de ejemplos tomados [de aqui](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Examples) que pueden servirte de referencia.

```
simple@example.com
very.common@example.com
disposable.style.email.with+symbol@example.com
other.email-with-hyphen@example.com
fully-qualified-domain@example.com
user.name+tag+sorting@example.com (may go to user.name@example.com inbox depending on mail server)
x@example.com (one-letter local-part)
example-indeed@strange-example.com
admin@mailserver1 (local domain name with no TLD, although ICANN highly discourages dotless email addresses[10])
example@s.example (see the List of Internet top-level domains)
" "@example.org (space between the quotes)
"john..doe"@example.org (quoted double dot)
mailhost!username@example.org (bangified host route used for uucp mailers)
user%example.com@example.org (% escaped mail route to user@example.com via example.org)
```

Comment: Gracias @Legna por responder, pero si escribo por ejemplo "holaa", me informa que ingrese un formato de email valido, sigo llenando los otros campos del formulario, cuando estoy borrando el email del input se habilita el boton de submit, eso es lo que no entiendo

Answer (score 1):

Tu Validator esta mal ubicado,
tu versión:

```
buildForm() {
    this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
      email: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(80), Validators.email]],
      username: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(50)]],
      password: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(80)]],
      password2: ['', [Validators.required], {validator: this.checkPasswords }]
    });
  }
```

como deberia estar:

```
buildForm() {
    this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
      email: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(80), Validators.email]],
      username: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(50)]],
      password: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(80)]],
      password2: ['', [Validators.required] ]
    }, {validator: this.checkPasswords});
  }
```